# Print prime numbers in columns and rows to a file

Tags: c++

I created a function that finds prime numbers and I need help writing those numbers to a file in a well-formatted table with columns and rows. I think I'll need some nested loops, but I don't know what could be the best implementations. Here is my code so far, I hope you guys could help me. Thanks

Right now what my code does is write the number 2 and 3 to the file and then it goes on an infinite loop of empty lines.

The file should look like this:

```
2  3  5  11  13  17  19  23
```

29 31 37 41  43  47  53

... All the way up to closest prime number to 4000

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int currentNumber = 2;
    ofstream outputFile("test.txt");

    for (int i = 2; i < 4000; i++)
    {

            for (int row = 1; row < 4000; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 1; col <= 8; col++)
                {
                    if (isPrime(i) == true)
                    {
                        outputFile << endl;
                        outputFile << setw(8);
                        outputFile << i;
                        outputFile << setw(10);

                        i++;

                    }   

                }
                outputFile << endl;
            }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Tell us something. No one knows the problem(s) better than you.

Comment: I don't know how to get all the prime numbers from 1-4000 in a well-formatted table on a file. Like, how can I set up my code in a manner that it prints 8 prime numbers per line and do the same until the last number?

Comment: No, we want to know what problem you have with the code you showed us. What does the code do or not do that it shouldn't do or should do?

Comment: Right now, it just writes the number 2 and 3 and then it goes on an infinite loop of empty lines.

Comment: Now edit your OP and put that in it. You won't get downvoted as much.

Comment: prime.cc:39:19: error: ‘system’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close. Just count up to 8 primes and print out a new line, then reset the counter until the next 8. You have duplicated the i++ inside the loop as well as on the "for" line, the row and col stuff is all unecessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    ofstream outputFile("test.txt");

    for (int i = 2; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        if (isPrime(i) == true)
        {
            outputFile << setw(8);
            outputFile << i;
            outputFile << setw(10);
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == 8)
        {
            outputFile << endl;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second `setw()`?

Comment: I just wanted to separate the output from each other and the left margin.

Comment: @beginnerdev AFAIK `setw()` pre-sets a width for the next value output, but doesn't print any spaces itself. So, the width of `10` will be overwritten by `setw(8)` in the next iteration. If you want to force a space at left, use the `std::right` modifier to align the output data to the right end of the field defined with `setw()`, like this: `outputFile << setw(10) << right << i;` Please see C++ Ref for [std::left, std::right](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Answer (score 0):

Richq already gave you a better way to implement this but lets look at what you did wrong in your code (looking at your intent, not always what it does):

Your outer loop goes from 2 to 4000. For each number you then print a table. (Not really since you increment i inside the table too but lets ignore that.) This is somewhat wrong. You only ever want one table so the outer loop has to go. Keep the `int i = 2;` though.

Second loop: row goes from 1 to 4000, printing 8 prime numbers per line. But you only want numbers smaller than 4000. Clearly 4000 * 8 primes will be larger. You don't know how many lines of table you will need. Your exit condition for the rows should be `i < 4000` instead.

Third loop: col goes from 1 to 8. But maybe on the last line i will exceed 4000 on the 3rd number. So if i < 4000 is a hard limit (instead of printing till the end of the line even if you already reached 4000) then you need to include that in the condition: `(col <= 8) && (i < 4000)`.

Inner part has 2 problems:

- You print a new line before every prime number. That's why you get a single 2 and 3 in a line instead of both in the same line.
- You increment i only if i is a prime number. So after 2 and 3 your increment i. But then you have 4 and the rest of your table will just test that 4 is not a prime and print nothing.

Move the newline out of the inner loop. You need to only do that after each row. And inside the row always increment i. But only increment col if you found a prime number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


bool isPrime(int);

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int currentNumber = 2;
    ofstream outputFile("test.txt");

    int i = 2;
    for (int row = 1; i < 4000; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; (col <= 8) && (i < 4000); i++)
        {
            if (isPrime(i) == true)
            {
                outputFile << setw(8);
                outputFile << i;
                outputFile << setw(10);
                col++;
             }   
         }
         outputFile << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This makes absolute sense.